# Авторизация для нескольких проектов на разных поддоменах

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, развертывание

Идея такая - должно быть несколько проектов, у каждого свой поддомен, и отдельный поддомен со страницей авторизации, общей для всех проектов. После ввода логина и пароля пользователь сможет перейти на любой из доступных ему проектов, то есть аккаунт один, но он может быть как во всех проектах так и в одном или двух. Как такое лучше огранизовать? Сейчас есть один проект на Laravel, и один старый на puthon, который тоже будет переписан на Laravel и скорей всего будет использовать ту же базу. 
Как это лучше организовать?
Возможно просто будет одна база, один бекенд, и разные роуты для каждого проэкта, а роботать все бедет через апи, а на каждом поддомене свое SPA. Или SPA тоже одно, но с разных доменов чтоб работало. Главная проблема в том чтоб переходя на другой поддомен пользователь не перелогинивался.

например я делаю так

```
Route::domain('{login}' . env('SESSION_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('test', function () {
        return 'hello!';
    });
});
```

Этот роут test не работает, но если его вытащить из   `Route::domain('{login}' . env('SESSION_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {` то он работает, причем независимо от того поддомен это или нет

Answer (score 2):

Если все поддомены будут одного домена, то проблемы нет, просто нужно указать в конфиге сессий `config/session.php` параметр `domain`, к примеру вот так:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

И в своем `.env` файле указать:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
```

И теперь пользователь может ходить по всем поддоменам и быть авторизованым.

Comment: Пока что не получилось, сейчас например поставил SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost:8000 (локально запускаю через php artisan serve) и у меня перестало запоминать логин и выдает мне сейчас "The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again. "

Comment: Так скорее всего и не будет работать, нужно настроить хосты для доменов и нормально его запустить, а не через standalone, у меня аналогичный есть сайт с кучей поддоменов и всё работает.

Comment: А вот это сложнее. Как их настроить? Я так понимаю надо что бы с разных поддоменов переходило в одну и ту же папку

Comment: В настройках апача в вашем случае отправляете всех в папку с проектом, и на стороне фреймворка если вам это нужно в роутах отправляете уже куда требуется каждый поддомен.